# VHDL testing feedback circuits

Tags: vhdl

how do you test circuits with output signals which feedback into the input circuit?
Below is an example of a test bench i wrote, the `current_iteration` and `current_address` should feedback into the inputs of `previous_iteration` and `previous_address`. However in the simulation it shows that the inputs are basically uninitialized shown by `U`.

How to solve this problem, would creating another entity which transfers the output signals into the inputs work?

[image]

```
library IEEE;
library work;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity addr_iter_tb is
end addr_iter_tb;

architecture Behavioral of addr_iter_tb is
    
        --Clocking signals
        signal clk_tb : std_logic:='0';
        constant time_period : time:= 1 ns;
        
        --Stimulus signals    
        signal reset: std_logic:='1'; --Active low reset
        signal enable: std_logic:='1'; --By default enabled
        signal previous_address: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        signal max_iteration:  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        signal previous_iteration: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
        
        signal cycle_iteration_out: std_logic;
        signal bm_completed: std_logic;
        signal read_address: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        signal current_address: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        signal current_iteration: std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);

begin

    addr_iter_instance : entity work.addr_iter port map (
        clk=>clk_tb, reset=>reset, enable=>enable, previous_address=>current_address,
        max_iteration=>max_iteration, previous_iteration=>current_iteration,
        cycle_iteration_out=>cycle_iteration_out, bm_completed=>bm_completed, 
        read_address=>read_address, current_address=>current_address,
        current_iteration=>current_iteration
    );
    
    clocking_process : process begin
        wait for time_period;
        clk_tb <= not clk_tb;
    end process;
    
    stimulus_process : process begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 1 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        enable <= '1';
        max_iteration <= "00010";
        wait;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Just create a signal in the TB  and assign it to both component ports that need to be connected.

Comment: I have done that in the test bench, it doesnt work

Comment: Then it doesn't work for some other reason.

Comment: Does it work for you? What version of Vivado are you using?

Comment: Nobody else can test it without the DUT, where the problem almost certainly lies, and which only you have. Is its "current_address" port an OUT port and its "previous_address" an IN port for example? Is the driver for that OUT port initialised on RESET? Do all the signals contributing to that driver have the correct values? Examine what's happening INSIDE the DUT.

Comment: Yes, current_address is Out, previous_address is In. Yes the output signals are initialized on reset. Yes they have correct values.

Comment: I've update the question to show the DUT

Comment: I dont think the problem is with my circuit, because it works perfectly part from the feedbacks are not showing

Answer (score 2):

Both DUT ports Prev_Address and Curr_Address connect to signal Curr_Address, and work fine, delivering the Curr_Address output to the Prev_Address input of the DUT.

Signal Prev_Address in the TB is simply unused. No initialisation, no drivers, no assignments to it.

What you're displaying as "UU" is just a redundant signal, not the Prev_Address input port value (which is the Curr_Address signal)

If you insist on seeing a value on it, `Pre_Address <= Curr_Address;` in the concurrent region of the TB. And then you could map the Prev_Address port to the Prev_Address signal, in the port map.

But, best solution : just delete it.

And if you want to see the values on the input port Prev_Address, learn enough Vivado simulator to find its "add signal addr_iter_instance/Prev_Address to Wave Window" command or menu option.

Comment: What simulation are you using and do you mind showing some pictures of it working? Im using Vivado so it could be different

Comment: This is not sim dependent and I'm not going to sim it. Plus, see update (coming)

Comment: So how do you know it works then? lol

Comment: a quarter century experience using VHDL count for anything? lol

Comment: Okay so what simulation tool have you used which shows the correct values for the current feedback structure. In, Out ports, and a signal connection

Comment: Accolade PeakHDL, Modelsim, Questa, GHDL, Xilinx ISE Simulator, Vivado.

Comment: Okay so for my simulation in Vivado, why does it not work given that you've verified the VHDL DUT is correct?

Comment: Already explained. What you're displaying is not the Prev_Address port value but a completely unrelated (and completely disconnected) signal, which just happens to have the same name. And because that is uninitialised, it displays "UU"

Comment: I dont think you know what you're on about tbh. but its been solved with a concurrent assignment

Comment: You have the DUT, what is the unrelated signal though

Comment: You're a funny guy.  And you never posted the DUT; all we have is the testbench. Which contains the unrelated `signal previous_address: std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);` which is never assigned, and displays as UU

Comment: I dont want to argue with you, but that's not the reason. But i thank you for your suggestions

Comment: The DUT was added, but it was too long so i removed it. Since it'd be bothersome for people to go through it

Answer (score 0):

That is another thing I had, very long long time ago. So, I forgot how I managed, but throwing a random thoughts (again). Please pardon me of using incorrect terminologies.

Since, you do not want to connect the signals internally;

1. Can the simulator take multiple "modules" and route the signals between modules (named signal)? Then you may use a module that passes signals around.
2. Can the to-be-simulated module become a sub package, so the signals can be routed through the top module?

Comment: Yes it can take multiple modules. Im not sure about the second

Comment: @LinusMagnola that is a good news! I will use that when time comes. Thanks.